# New contest type proposal: cross-codes

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, winning-criteria

Cross-codes is making a crossword puzzle, but with codes.

For example, We have a 10*10 (not constant, this means the size may vary for each contest) grid:

```
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
```

And your code is `MY_CODE`, you can place your code anywhere in the grid, vertically or horizontally.

For example:

```
..........
...MY_CODE
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
```

Next, Let's assume the next code is `MOM`.

The poster could place it like

```
..........
...MY_CODE
...O......
...M......
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
```

But not like:

```
..........
..MMY_CODE
..O.......
..M.......
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
```

Because it is adjacent to another code which is `MY_CODE`, making it look like `MMY_CODE`.

The winner would be the one with the most codes placed, when there is nobody able to place a new code on the grid for a set time period (ex.1 week).

Comment: @PeterTaylor I do not see why it is a dupe.

Comment: It's not the same question, but it should be an *answer* to that question.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I felt this criteria specifically needed so I made a criteria proposal

Comment: Hasn't it been done [already](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/57327/6741)?

Comment: Yeah, this isn't a challenge type, it's just a single challenge, which should be posted in the sandbox. It's also already been done.